# Have option conditionally require package

Tags: packages, package-writing, package-options

I want to declare an option in my package that, if provided, will require another package. However, just doing

```latex
\DeclareOption{requiresomething}{
    \RequirePackage{somepackage}
}
```

does not work, as you can't mix package requiring with the Option Section. Is there any simple solution to this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a conditional:

```
\ProvidesPackage{aachh}

\newif\ifaachh@array
\DeclareOption{array}{\aachh@arraytrue}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\ifaachh@array
  \RequirePackage{array}
\fi

\endinput
```

or define a macro

```
\ProvidesPackage{aachh}

\DeclareOption{array}{\let\aachh@array\@empty}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\@ifundefined{aachh@array}{}{%
  \RequirePackage{array}%
}

\endinput
```

The latter method is less memory intensive, but nowadays it's not really important.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!